# Need to know what some google permissions mean

Tags: macos, email, google-docs, phishing

I was a victim of yesterday's google doc phishing  attack. The email I received had a link and when clicked it asked for certain permissions. I gave access at that time but after few minutes I removed the permission from my google security page. However I am not sure what kind of permissions were given to the hacker. If I click on the link now the google page shows this message.

```
Error: disabled_client

The OAuth client was disabled.

Request Details
client_id=946634442539-bpj9bmemdvoedu8d3or6c69am3mi71dh.apps.googleusercontent.com
scope=https://mail.google.com/ https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts
immediate=false
include_granted_scopes=true
response_type=token
redirect_uri=https://googledocs.gdocs.pro/g.php
customparam=customparam
That’s all we know.
```

What kind of permissions were given to the hacker based on the above information? I am more interested in whether the hacker had access to my emails or not.

If they were able to gain access to my emails, is there a way to check whether or not they were able to successfully download my emails? I had removed the permission few minutes after giving access.

Answer (score 0):

The hacker had access to your contacts and your mail account, as visible in this line:

> scope=https://mail.google.com/
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts

Comment: Also, is there a way to check if they were able to download my emails or not?

Comment: I don't think so.